# Remove a Python array element by name

Tags: python, arrays, sorting

In a Python array, I need to know (**if possible**) how to delete an array element by its name, without knowing the index of the element in the array.

So, if I had this array defined

```
usernames = ["Billy", "Bob", "Apple"]
```

Then we would have three array elements.

**Billy**, **Bob**, and **Apple**.

And then if I had this code

```
# Deleting the element
def delete_username():
    to_delete = raw_input("Username to remove:")
    # (Code to delete by element name)
```

I need to know how to delete the element in the array by it's name.

For example, if the user entered "Billy," and the program didn't know the index of Billy in the array, how would we delete Billy from the array, just knowing its name?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can also use `remove`

```
usernames = ["Billy", "Bob", "Apple"]
if "Billy" in usernames:
    usernames.remove("Billy")
# usernames = ["Bob", "Apple"]
```

Comment: Extra brownie points to show the handling of the `ValueError` that will come up when the item is not in the list.

Comment: Actually just to clarify, is it better style to use `try:` and `except ValueError:`, or is this just as good?

Comment: Using a `try` `except ValueError` would work great here, because then you can control what you want to do in the event that the item does not actually exist in the list. However, it is entirely possible that you want the application to raise and crash in the event that an item does not exist. Personally, I would probably catch the error and provide a user friendly output, but log the traceback in a log file and exit.

Comment: something that came to mind. You might want the exception to raise in that method but wrap it in a try except outside that method to handle the accordingly. That would probably the better approach. Just thought I'd throw that out there as well

Answer (score 4):

You can use `remove()` method to remove the element. Check if the required element is present in the list before trying to delete it since a `ValueError` is raised if the element is not present in the list.

```
if to_delete in usernames:
  usernames.remove(to_delete)
```

Comment: @AshishAhujaツ, I have edited the answer. I will keep that in mind, thank you :)

Comment: @cpburnz, thank you. I have removed the break which was unnecessary .

Comment: @SilentMonk Thanks for doing that. Now the answer is much better.

Answer (score 0):

```
if to_delete in usernames:
    usernames.pop(usernames.index(to_delete))
```

That's it basically.

Comment: Why not just use `remove`?

Comment: I thought remove also took an index as parameter @idjaw. Guess I was wrong. Anyway, this works, Greg's method is more elegant though.

Answer (score 0):

```
def remove_by_name(name):
    if name in usernames:
        usernames.remove(name)
```

Remove only first occurrence, if you want all elements, modify the sample above.

Answer (score 0):

You can use remove function `array.remove(value)` or use index `array.index(value)` function and get the index of the particular value and remove it using `del array[x]`.

```
arr=['Billy', 'Bob', 'Apple']
arr.remove('Bob')
print(arr) #['Billy', 'Apple'] 

#OR you can use 

indexValue = arr.index('Billy')
del arr[indexValue]
print(arr) #['Bob', 'Apple']
```